How can I use the values of one plot in another one?
I have a two functions that I have to plot versus Q:

the first is Ri which is a solution for eqn==0 below,
the second isZk given below,

where g is a parameter, Ri and Q are real variables.
As for plotting Ri Vs Q, I did not manage to solve eqn==0 for Ri=r. Thanks to @Bob_Hanlon, the solution was as follows
   Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = -8 Q^4 + r^3 (2 M + g Log[g] - g Log[r]) + 
   r (2 (4 g + 9 M) Q^2 + 9 g Q^2 Log[g] - 9 g Q^2 Log[r]) + 
   r^2 (-2 g^2 - 8 g M - 12 M^2 - 4 g^2 Log[g] - 12 g M Log[g] + 
      4 g^2 Log[r] + 12 g M Log[r] + 
      3 g^2 Log[g] (-Log[g] + Log[r]) - 
      3 g^2 Log[r] (-Log[g] + Log[r]));
M = 1;
ContourPlot[
 Limit[eqn, g -> 0] == 0, {Q, 0, 0.8}, {r, 4, 6.6}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Q, "Ri"}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"g=0"}, {Top, Right}]]

I used the Limit for g because there was Log[g]. The resulted graph was

The second function I have to draw is Zk versus Q such that
      Zk=(re Sqrt[-2 Q^2 + g re + 2 M re + g re Log[g] - g re Log[re]])/(Sqrt[
     Q^2 - 2 M re + re^2 - g re Log[g] + g re Log[re]] Sqrt[
4 Q^2 - g re - 6 M re + 2 re^2 - 3 g re Log[g] + 3 g re Log[re]])

where M=1,g->{0,0.06,0.1,0.3} and re=Ri of the plot above.
Here comes my question: how can I plot Zk versus Q if I dont have the values of Ri? I only get its plot (above) versus Q!
In other words, is there any way to use the values of RiVsQ from the above plot in the second plot of Zk versus Q?
I would be very grateful if someone help me in this.

Never use upper-case letters to name variables in Mathematica as they can conflict with the internal names of functions and certain numbers.

Please provide a concrete example of what you are trying to do and show what you have tried.

Ok @DavidG.Stork and @Bob Hanlon , I hope things are clear now. My problem is, with M=1, g->{0,0.06,0.1,0.3} being fixed, how can get the values of Ri=reVsQ from the plot above, in order to plot Zk Vs Q?

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

M = 1;

eqn = -8  Q^4 + r^3  (2  M + g  Log[g] - g  Log[r]) + 
    r  (2  (4  g + 9  M)  Q^2 + 9  g  Q^2  Log[g] - 
       9  g  Q^2  Log[r]) + 
    r^2  (-2  g^2 - 8  g  M - 12  M^2 - 4  g^2  Log[g] - 
       12  g  M  Log[g] + 4  g^2  Log[r] + 12  g  M  Log[r] + 
       3  g^2  Log[g]  (-Log[g] + Log[r]) - 
       3  g^2  Log[r]  (-Log[g] + Log[r])) // Simplify;

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[
  Simplify[Limit[eqn, g -> #]] == 0 & /@ {0, 3/50, 1/10, 3/10}],
 {Q, 0, 0.8}, {r, 4, 6.6},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Q, "Ri"}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{0, 0.06, 0.1, 0.3},
    LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[g], 14]],
   {Top, Right}]]


Ri[Qv_?NumericQ, gv_?NumericQ] :=
 SolveValues[
   Limit[eqn /. Q -> Rationalize[Qv, 0], g -> Rationalize[gv, 0]] == 
    0, r, Reals][[1]]

Zk[Q_?NumericQ, gv_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {re = Ri[Q, gv]},
  Limit[(re  Sqrt[-2  Q^2 + g  re + 2  M  re + g  re  Log[g] - 
        g  re  Log[re]])/(Sqrt[
       Q^2 - 2  M  re + re^2 - g  re  Log[g] + g  re  Log[re]]  Sqrt[
       4  Q^2 - g  re - 6  M  re + 2  re^2 - 3  g  re  Log[g] + 
        3  g  re  Log[re]]), g -> gv]]

Plot[
 Evaluate[Zk[Q, #] & /@ {0, 3/50, 1/10, 3/10}],
 {Q, 10^-3, 0.8},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Q, "Zk"}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{0, 0.06, 0.1, 0.3},
    LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[g], 14]],
   {Top, Right}]]



I am really grateful for your help @Bob Hanlon. I break it down step by step. Everything was ok, till I reach the SolveValues , which does not seem to be a build-in function in my Mathematica 12.0.
Do you have any solution?

r /. Solve[..., r] is equivalent to SolveValues[..., r]

Ok, thank you so much again @Bob Hanlon.
